# Error when build for production in ionic 2

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

i got this problem when i enter following code to build my app to production
can anyone help me in this problem my all project stop because off this

ionic build android --prod

i got this error

```html
[22:09:48] ionic-app-script task: "build" 
[22:09:48] TypeError: Cannot read property 'codeGen' of undefined 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'codeGen' of undefined
at Object.doCodegen (/Users/ali/Desktop/ionic 2 fin/test/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/codegen.js:6:50)
at /Users/ali/Desktop/ionic 2 fin/test/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:42:30
```

my system info is

```html
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.4
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.2
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.4
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: 5.0.13 
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.10.2
Xcode version: Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002
```

**package.json**

```html
{
"name": "ionic-hello-world",
"author": "Ionic Framework",
"homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
"ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
},
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "2.2.1",
"@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.1",
"@angular/core": "2.2.1",
"@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
"@angular/http": "2.2.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
"@angular/platform-server": "2.2.1",
"@ionic/storage": "1.1.6",
"ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"ionic-native": "2.2.11",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
"ngrx-store-localstorage": "^0.1.6",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
"zone.js": "0.6.26"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@ionic/app-scripts": "^1.3.4",
"typescript": "2.0.9"
},
"cordovaPlugins": [
"ionic-plugin-keyboard",
"cordova-plugin-whitelist",
"cordova-plugin-console",
"cordova-plugin-statusbar",
"cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
"cordova-plugin-device"
],
"cordovaPlatforms": [],
"description": "PHPCRUD: An Ionic project"
}
```

Comment: How you solved your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Angular is outdated, see:

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts/issues/918